# Does the option results = 'asis' work in xaringan presentation?

Tags: r-markdown, xaringan

I'm trying to create various slides in `xaringan` presentation using the option `results='assis'` of knitr, but it doesn't work.

I have use the following code:

````
    ---
    title: "Presentation"
    author: ""
    date: ""
    output:
      xaringan::moon_reader:
        lib_dir: libs
        nature:
          highlightStyle: github
          highlightLines: true
          countIncrementalSlides: false
    ---

    ```{r, results='asis'}
    for (i in 1:3) {  
      cat("---", "\n")
      cat("## Slide", i, "\n")
      cat("Hello", i)
      cat("\n")
    }
   '''
````

I expect the output to be 3 pages, but the actual output is one page. I have also tried `asis_output` instead of `cat`.

Answer (score 1):

You nearly had it. Change

```
cat("---", "\n")
```

to

```
cat("---\n")
```

The former adds a space between `---` and `\n` and in `xaringan`/`remark.js` there should be no space after `---` otherwise it becomes a horizontal rule.